# Get drawable from other resource folder

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I've a project structure like that:

[image]

The folder "coffee_types" is an Android resource folder with type drawable created in the following way:

[image]

Previously, when I was using only main drawables folder, I was using this function to get the Drawable object:

```
private Drawable getDrawableByName(String name) {
    return getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

I was trying to change it to make it work with the "coffee_types" folder with no success.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The folder "coffee_types" is an Android resource folder with type drawable

No, it is not. You cannot invent your own resource types.

Comment: So why it is possible to create "New resource directory" and it is possible to set the resources type (I've added and image) ? What is it for ?

Comment: @PiotrSagalara: I have no idea.

Comment: I think I figured why in IDEA you can add a new resource directory - you can have different folders for different languages support.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access drawables from another directory.
But you could name the pictures like: "coffee_image_1", "coffee_image_2" etc. (like you did) and put them in the drawables folder.
It will be easier to find them this way.

Comment: That is just very sad...if you have bigger application it's going to be a huge mess. Still cannot believe that there is no work-around for it.

Comment: @Piotr Sagalara yeah, if you decompile an open source program and take a look in the drawables folder, you'll see it's messy. There's no way to create a new directory for drawables.